# JUnit and EntityTransaction

Tags: junit, eclipselink, h2, entitymanager, java-ee-7

My base class

```
public abstract class JPABaseIT {

    protected static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    protected static EntityManager em;
    protected static EntityTransaction tx;

    protected JPABaseIT() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(getPersistenceUnit());
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        tx = em.getTransaction();
    }

    protected abstract String getPersistenceUnit();

    protected abstract String getCleanQuery();

    @Before
    public void initTx(){
        tx.begin();
        em.createNativeQuery(getCleanQuery()).executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
        tx.begin();
    }

    @After
    public void endTx() {
        if(tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            if(!tx.getRollbackOnly()) {
                tx.commit();
            } else {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownEM() {
        if (em != null) {
            em.clear();
            if (em.isOpen()) {
                em.close();
            }
            if (emf.isOpen()) {
                emf.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test (without building a context, using EM directly)

```
public class FooBeanIT extends JPABaseIT {

    protected FooBean service;


    public FooBeanIT() {
        service = new FooBean();
        service.setEntityManager(em);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPersistenceUnit() {
        return "foo-TEST";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getCleanQuery() {
        return "TRUNCATE TABLE FOO;";
    }

    
    @Test
    public void updateFoo_test() {

        service.addFoo();   // -> em.persist()
        service.updateFooStatus(); // -> em.createNamedQuery().executeUpdate()
        Foo actual = service.getFooById();  // -> em.find()

    }

}
```

`actual` is returned but is not updated. I've tried to do `tx.commit(); tx.begin();` after the update but is like being ignored. How should I get my entity updated in this kind of tests with multiple operations?

Comment: service.getFooById() is likely returning the instance you created in service.addFoo(). Since this is the same EntityManager context, you get the same unaltered instance. You need to do something (like em.clear()) to force it to go to the database to load the data on the service.getFooById call. You might want to just close the EntityManager and obtain a new one when committing transactions.

Comment: @Chris yes, using em.clear() before fetching works. Still, I have another test scenario that I dont know how to fix: I want to test `service.updateFooStatus(); Exception actual = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> tx.commit());` for non-existing entity but no Exception is thrown.

Comment: Never mind, I just realized by looking javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate-- that there is no such exception to be expected. I have to check the return value instead. The only thing about ur solution is that it somehow makes the code cumbersome having to do this kind of stuff instead if JUnit providing a proper solution but is ok